# PL/SQL developer pop up error message

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I accidentally disabled the pop-up error message for PL/SQL developer, is there a way to enable it? I have tried searching google and various of forums but did not find the correct answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Tools -> Preferences -> User Interface -> Options -> DSA Dialogs...`

Comment: For whom not get what to do in dialog: Erase line `ViewStackDump=...` . Press  Ok twice, and voila! :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! That was really hard to find. This tool has a lot of problems like this, I will switch to something else.

Comment: I do not see the "User Interface" in Preferences in Oracle SQL Developer 22.2.1.234

Answer (score 2):

[image: You have to follow below steps :]

- Open Tools > Preferences
- Click on User Interface > Options
- Click on DSA Dialogs... button
- Removes the lines with StackTrace